# Checking whether a given Hashing Function fulfills Uniform Hashing Condition

Tags: hashing

I am learning about Hashing and have struggles with the following assignment:

> $U$ is a universe of keys with $Z(m)=\{0,\ldots, m-1 \}$  the amount of possible hash-values.
>
> Given $U= \mathbb{Z}_{55} = \{0, \ldots, 54 \}$ and $m=5$.
>
> Does the function $h(k,i)= (k+i) \bmod{5}$ fulfill the conditions for Uniform Hashing?

Uniform Hashing should be given when the probability that to a random key, a specific probe sequence trough the hash function is assigned, is $1/m!$ for all possible probe sequences...
But I don't know how to proceed with checking whether this is given for the function above.

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated! :)

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it go wrong? Do you have an example of a proof or disproof of uniform hashing that you **do** understand? If not, that is a good place to start.

Comment: Well, I guess I have to give it more thought... I do think that I understand why linear probing and quadratic probing are not good approxmations to uniform hashing, following the explanations found here (p.5): http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/wiki/pub/ABI/AnalysisMethods/discMath_script.pdf